# Comparator Implementation Fails to Sort

Tags: java, android, comparator

I have implemented a Comparator class to sort elements of a list based on their sizes. The code goes as follows:

```
public class SizeComparator implements Comparator< AppModel> {

    @Override
    public int compare( AppModel lhs, AppModel rhs ) {
         double i1 = lhs.getCache();
         double i2 = rhs.getCache();

        if ( i1 > i2 )return +1;
        else if (i1 < i2 )return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Method getCache() returns double.

The sort function is called like this:

```
Collections.sort(installedApps, new SizeComparator());
```

But still the apps are not sorted based on their sizes. Don't know where I am going wrong. Could some one help me out?

Comment: What output did you get? Are none of the items sorted, or some of them are sorted? Is there no change in the original order of elements? Please share some more details.

Comment: Even though your code is functionally correct, you should replace it with `Double.compare(lhs.getCache(), rhs.getCache()` because that way there's much less chance of ever getting it wrong.

Comment: Code looks good, provide some more informations

Comment: Could it be that `getCache` does not return the desired size?

Comment: There is a change in after calling sort but the order is neither ascending nor descending order

Comment: but on UI I could able to see the sizes,which is again getting value form getCache()

Comment: But if the method `getCache` does not return a stable value, then the sorting can not work. What exactly `getCache` returns? Can we see the implementation (if it is feasible)?

Comment: I have method which gives me apps list and I'm storing app name and its cache info to installedApps.

Comment: I think getCache() is stable enough to justify my statement

Comment: Collections.sort(installedApps, new SizeComparator()); here I've passed installedApps list, which contains stable values isn't it?

Comment: Add code for AppModel. That will make the picture clearer..